# Error 403 MCPMediaTypeBlocked: acorn@3.3.0 when running `npm install` for a cloned react web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-redux, npm-install

The `npm install` error is below:

> ```
> npm ERR! code E403
> npm ERR! 403 MCPMediaTypeBlocked: acorn@3.3.0
> ```

Below are the versions of node and npm I have presently.

```
node : v10.10.0
npm : 6.4.1
```

This react application is an application already being ran by my colleagues. However, after I cloned the application and tried run the command `npm install`, it fails everytime. I have tried re-installing node and npm (I use nvm to do so), and it still gives me the same error. I tried to create a new react app and the same error occurs too.

```
{
  "name": "my-new-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ajv": "^6.5.4",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "resolve": "1.6.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.5",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.3",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3",
    "prop-types": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build-prod": "node scripts/prod.js",
    "build-stage": "node scripts/stage.js",
    "build-dev": "node scripts/develop.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "svg-loader": "0.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What application is it? Can you give us a way to reproduce it (Perhaps another package.json file with the dependency that is causing the issue)?

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks for the help in editing. It is a react web application.